# Unable to save to Elastic search with correct index

Tags: elasticsearch, entity, spring-data-elasticsearch, jmstemplate

I'm getting data from service bus queue using jms Template receive method and then saving received data into elasticsearch. I have also created an endpoint for this . The issue I'm facing is first time when I'm hitting endpoint , it will fetch data from service bus and save it in elastic search. Again, if I hit my endpoint it's overwriting the index with new records. But I need to insert it as a new index , without replacing existing index data. All existing processed data should remain in the elastic search, it shouldn't overwrite.
Like a primary key works while insertion as in a relational database.similar approach

```
Public void fetch () { List entities = new ArrayList<>();

Message m=jmsTemplate.receive("queue"); Product p=messageConverter.fromMessage(m); saveToElasticSearch (p, entities);

} private void saveToElasticSearch(Product p, List entities){

elasticEntity e = new elasticEntity(); e.setName(p.getName()); e setPrice(p.getPrice()); entities.add(e); repository.saveAll(entities);

}
```

In my entity class I have declared @Id Id Name and price variables

Comment: not clear what you want. Do you want to create a new index every time you call your endpoint or do you want to save the new entries into the same index - as you are not setting id values, these would be autogenerated and would not overwrite existing entities.